# "Be late" vs. "run late"

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say it's 8:30 an I am getting ready for work. My  work starts at 9:00 and it takes 35 minutes to get to work. Do I say ***I am late*** or ***I am running late***? Can I use **I am late** and **I am running late** with the same meaning if I still have chance to get somewhere in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be "late for work" until you arrive at your workplace after the normal starting time. You are behind your normal morning schedule, so most people would say that you are "running late".